# Letter edth for latex

Tags: math-operators, letters

I would like to use the Icelandic letter "edth" in latex equations (for context, I am working with the [GHP formalism](https://aip.scitation.org/doi/10.1063/1.1666410)). Is there a Latex package for this letter (and others)? I have tried using "\dh" but I get an error from latex (I am using TeX Live 2019/dev/Debian).

EDIT:
The particular error I am getting is:

```
! LaTeX Error: Command \dh unavailable in encoding OT1.
```

so perhaps there is a package I should be using. At the moment I am using

```
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
```

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx.  You might try entering it as `\textup{\dh}`.  (You tagged it as a math operator, so the upright form seems appropriate.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're not short with symbol fonts:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\DeclareSymbolFont{TOneChars}{T1}{\familydefault}{m}{it}
\SetSymbolFont{TOneChars}{bold}{T1}{\familydefault}{bx}{it} % or b
\DeclareMathSymbol{\mathdh}{\mathord}{TOneChars}{"F0}

\DeclareMathOperator{\ghpwhatsit}{\mathdh}

\begin{document}

$\ghpwhatsit A$

$\ghpwhatsit(A)$

\end{document}
```

Use a more meaningful name for the operator.

[image]

If you're short with symbol fonts, do

```latex
\newcommand{\mathdh}{\textit{\dh}}
```

instead of the first three declarations in the example above.

Answer (score 1):

If you can use either LuaLaTeX or XeLaTeX, you can load `unicode-math` or `fontspec` and use the Unicode character.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{unicode-math}

\newcommand\matheth{\mathord{\textnormal{ð}}}

\begin{document}
\( \matheth x \)
\end{document}
```

[image: Latin Modern sample]

If you use PDFLaTeX, you must load the 8-bit T1 encoding from 1990, instead of the even-more-obsolete default seven-bit encoding from the 1980s.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % The default since 2018
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand\matheth{\mathord{\textnormal{ð}}}

\begin{document}
\( \matheth x \)
\end{document}
```

[image: Computer Modern sample]

In either case, you could get an italic *ð* with `\newcommand\matheth{\mathord{\text{\normalfont\itshape ð}}}`.  You probably want to be consistent with the slant of `\partial` and `\delta`.  If you want the letter to appear bold if the surrounding text is bolded—such as in a chapter or section heading—use `\textup` or `\textit` instead of `\textnormal`.

Comment: Sigh, please stop using `\text` for things like this. it is not the proper method. Try adding a `\itshape` before `\(` and see what happens, not a good idea for a math operator to change its shape depending on the context of the surrounding text. use `\textup` or `\textnormal` (there are so many users who use `\text` wrongly)

Comment: @daleif Good point—although `\textup` will still inherit a `\bfseries` or the like, which might or might not be what you want. (Could be desirable in a heading.)

Comment: Good point, texrnormal ought to be correct then

Answer (score 0):

It is also useful to remember that `mathalfa` + `amssymb` provide to give the symbol `\eth`. See the example below:

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{mathalfa,amssymb}
\begin{document}
\[\frac{\eth f}{\eth y}\]
\end{document}
```

This is also the version with the complet `mtpro2` package, that is better than the previous code:
[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{mtpro2}
\begin{document}
$\eth$
\end{document}
```

**ADDENDUM:** The user asked "is there a way to get the icelandic letter "thorn" as well?"

Personally, like using a phonetic symbol in mathematical mode, I am not able to do this. I can only add how to write symbols `\eth` e `\thorn` in text mode using another package called `ipa`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{ipa}
\begin{document}
\eth, \thorn
\end{document}
```

Comment: is there a way to get the icelandic letter "thorn" as well? I get an error when I try "\thorn" with mathalfa+amssymb