# How to place a slash (/) over the letter ð?

Tags: unicode, strikeout, diacritical-mark

How can I type the letter `ð` with a slash across it? I have tried the solutions proposed in [How can I place a "slash" -- / -- through a letter in this way?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/416345/how-can-i-place-a-slash-through-a-letter-in-this-way) but they do not work for the letter `ð`, or letters with diacritics like `á` or `ä`.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Linux Libertine O}

\usepackage{cancel}

\begin{document}

$\cancel{d}$
$\cancel{ð}$

${d\mkern-7.5mu/}$
${ð\mkern-7.5mu/}$

\end{document}
```

Comment: Do you have tested \not?

Comment: The log says clearly that there is no `ð` in the math font. But I'm not really sure this should actually be math... what's the symbol's purpose?

Comment: @Sebastiano Then `\cancel{ð}` does it.

Comment: I am citing a source that uses that symbol. It's used to show that the letter isn't pronounced.

Comment: @campa Is this an help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67884480/why-cant-i-show-the-%C3%B0-symbol-in-latex? or https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/508106/letter-edth-for-latex

Comment: @campa You can see if the 2nd link it is a possible related with the question?

Comment: never use both of these in the same document `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}\usepackage{fontspec}`  use ``\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` with pdftex and `\usepackage{fontspec}`  with luatex/xetex

Comment: @user278663 this seems to be a text use not math then.

Comment: @Sebastiano both of those links are about 8-bit pdftex fonts so not relevant here.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I have undersood. Thank you very much always.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use Unicode Combining /.

Unicode has two, short U+0337 ̷  and long U+0338 ̸

The exact  positioning on the base character depends on the font

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
% no!\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Linux Libertine O}


\begin{document}

 d ð ä d̷ ð̷ ä̷ d̸ ð̸ ä̸

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you. Can you explain how to generate those for other letters? I can copy and use the ones you posted but don't know how to substitute the letter.

Comment: @user278663  it depends on your editor, how did you type ð in your question?  If it is not clear how to enter  ̷  You can use `^^^^0337` for  the short one and `^^^^0338` for long  so `ð^^^^0337` or even `^^f0^^^^0337`  for an all ascii version all make the same output.

Comment: I use Overleaf and just copy and paste the characters that are not in my keyboard.

Comment: @user278663 you can copy  ̷  and put it after any base letter but using `^^^^0337` might be easier